# Insert html into table cells

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

this is my  code but it shows data in div i want to show separate data in html table  like "First Name in one col , Last Name in second col , and qr code number in one col" , can anyone here who know to do that ?

```
var QrData = document.getElementById("qrdata");



let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner(
    {
        video: document.getElementById('preview')
    }
);
scanner.addListener('scan', function(content) {

    QrData.innerHTML = content;
});
Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(cameras => 
{
    if(cameras.length > 0){
        scanner.start(cameras[0]);
    } else {
        console.error("No Camera found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `table` element in HTML and setting QrData = a data cell in that table?

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? There's a *lot* of different ways to do this.